# WPF: Inject DataContext into DataTemplate View

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection

I have a control that has a child ContentControl whose view is set through a DataTrigger and DataTemplate.  What I would like to do, is set the DataContext of these controls to a property of my main DataContextViewModel.  My view code looks like so.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ManageTags">
            <local:TagsEditView DataContext="{Binding Path=TagsEditViewModel}">        
             </local:TagsEditView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ExportTags">
             <local:TagsExportView DataContext="{Binding Path=TagsExportViewModel}">
             </local:TagsExportView>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImportTags">
             <local:TagsImportView DataContext="{Binding Path=TagsImportViewModel}">
              </local:TagsImportView>
      </DataTemplate>
```

On the ViewModel of the containing view I have the following properties which I have confirmed are being set and updated correctly:

```
    public TagsExportViewModel TagsExportViewModel { get; set; }
    public TagsImportViewModel TagsImportViewModel { get; set; }
    public TagsEditViewModel TagsEditViewModel { get; set; }
```

All is fine till I Snoop the child views (TagsEditView,TagsImportView..) and then I see that the DataContext is not being set.

How on earth do I get these ViewModels into these views?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of Control is your local:TagsImportView and the other custom controls? What do they inherit from? And what is the Control whose data is being templated by your DataTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

For a ContentControl, you need to set the Content property, not the DataContext property. All of the child controls will then take their DataContext from the ContentControl's Content property.

Comment: So there is no way to change the DataContext based on the view that is being presented in the ContentControl?

Comment: @FlexFiend Can you explain why you think you need to change the DataContext?

Comment: I don't need to change the datacontext, I need to set it on those views.

Comment: A ContentControl doesn't do anything with the local DataContext. Instead, it renders the Content property.

Comment: I don't want to inject it into the ContentControl, I want to inject it into the triggered view that will occupy the ContentControl.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. The problem is that a ContentControl breaks the DataContext inheritance. Normally, a Control's DataContext is inherited from its parent's DataContext. However, ContentControl breaks that inheritance and relies on you to set the Content instead. Your views don't have any DataContext, so setting it to a binding on your local:TagsImportView (etc.) doesn't work. On your ContentControl, set the Content property to bind to the DataContext on self, like this: 
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure, but this should be how it should be done.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ManageTags" DataType="{x:Type vm:TagsEditViewModel}">
    <local:TagsEditView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ExportTags" DataType="{x:Type vm:TagsExportViewModel}">
    <local:TagsExportView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImportTags" DataType="{x:Type vm:TagsImportViewModel}">
    <local:TagsImportView />
</DataTemplate>
```

This is what they call it "ViewModel-first-MVVM."

Personally, I've only used this for `TabControl` so I'm no expert on this either. Most of the time I'd just go "View-first-MVVM."

```
<local:TagsEditView>
    <local:TagsEditView.DataContext>
        <vm:TagsEditViewModel />
    </local:TagsEditView.DataContext>
</local:TagsEditView>
<local:TagsExportView>
    <local:TagsExportView.DataContext>
        <vm:TagsExportViewModel />
    </local:TagsExportView.DataContext>
</local:TagsExportView>
<local:TagsImportView>
    <local:TagsImportView.DataContext>
        <vm:TagsImportViewModel />
    </local:TagsImportView.DataContext>
</local:TagsImportView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ContentControl` and its `ContentTemplate`.

`ContentTemplate` is used to customize `Content`.

So, here in your case you have to set `Content` in your `DataTrigger's  Setter`. And everything will fall in place. See sample below :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentVMindex}" Value="1">
  <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding VM1}"/>
  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource VM1Key}"/>
</DataTrigger>

<DataTemplate x:Key="VM1Key">
    <TextBlock Background="Green" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

So, in your case remove `DataContext` from your `DataTemplate`.